# Move TEMPLATE folder to another disk?

Tags: 2010, hive

A customer have very limited disk space and want to move the 14-hives TEMPLATE (`{14}\TEMPLATE`) folder to another disk. The only relocating of files and folders inside the 14-hive, *that I'm aware of*, is the [trace logs files which can be moved to another disk if the same disk location is present on all Web Front Ends](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg193966%28v=office.14%29.aspx#MonitoringSharePoint2010_TraceLogs). But moving the TEMPLATE folder sounds a lot trickier. Is it possible? And if it is possible – how do I move the TEMPLATE folder to another disk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the installation directory that been used by SharePoint installation while setting it up. You can get it's path using `SPUtility.GetGenericSetupPath`  but you can't change it.

Only way I can think is that you will need to configure a new farm on another machine and migrate, but that going to be pain too as if its heavily customized.

Comment: +1 So in one sense it is possible, but I guess not worth the trouble for the customers budget. Thanks for your reply!

Comment: nope it's not worth it as specially when you got better options there, I have done it before but luckily on development servers, I created a new form and then migrated all components, and it took me weeks to fix the errors because of customizations, e.g. custom site defintions..